# Issue with disabling Application Insights in Azure when it writes back to the Configuration file?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have created a .net App Service in Azure and Application Insights is turned on by default.  I want to disable Application Insights. So i go to the Menu on the right Application Insights and disable it.
But it leaves the following settings in the config file ,

```
"name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",   
"name": "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION",   
"name": "APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION",   
"name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",   
"name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",   
"name": "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION",   
"name": "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION",   
"name": "SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION",   
"name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions",   
"name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Java",
"name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
"name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_NodeJS",
"name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_PreemptSdk",
```

Can i simply delete these and the required settings will be set once I save the config , or is there any setting i can set that will remove and clean the config file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had repro’d by disabling application insights in app service and found app service is working as expected.

Find the repro process that I have followed

Before repro:

When ***Application insight is enabled*** in the App service , below application settings will be shown

[image]

After ***disabling the application insights*** in App service it shows the list of new application settings.

[image]

Below are the list of application setting after **deleting the few config’s** and found that App service is working fine without any issues.

[image]

Later *deleted all the config’s* under the application settings and no issues found.

[image]

Note: Try it in a test environment or create a [staging environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) and try it.